# Posting image into an album. Facebook SDK for iOS Reference (v4.0.1)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to upload a picture to an specific album I already created on Facebook.

I have album ID. I was doing it with the old API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album) but I can't find any way to do it with the new one.

I'm currently posting a photo with

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
            photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:attachment.data];
            photo.userGenerated = YES;
            FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
            content.photos = @[photo];
            [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];
```

Also, I'd like to post a description on the photo.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the FBSDKShareAPI yourself instead of using the convenience method.

This worked for me:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:attachment.data];
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
FBSDKShareAPI *shareObject = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
shareObject.shareContent = content;
shareObject.graphNode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", FB_ALBUM_ID];
[shareObject share];
```

Where FB_ALBUM_ID is the Facebook graph id of the album you want to upload into.

Swift version:

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = image
photo.isUserGenerated = true

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [photo]

let shareObject = FBSDKShareAPI()
shareObject.shareContent = content
shareObject.graphNode = String(format:"/%@/photos", facebookAlbumId) 
shareObject.share()
```

BTW if you need a delegate you can set it on the shareObject

Comment: How to get facebookAlbumId?